# event.stopPropagation() doesn't work

Tags: openlayers, popup

I'm found out that event.stopPropagation() on Chrome and IE doesn't work.
In FireFox it's ok.

It is relevant with popup. When I have a few WFS layers I need prevent popup from lower layers as below pictures:

[image]

stopPropagation() in upper popup doesn't work so I have unnecessary popup from lower layer.
sample code popup:

```
function elem_id(id) {  return document.getElementById(id); }

//popup Open
var ol_popup = elem_id('ol_popup');
ol_popup.onmousemove = function(evn) {
   //evn.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
   //evn.preventDefault();  
   evn.stopPropagation();
  // tooltip.innerHTML = "";
   };
```

Code which some time ago (2 - 3 months) worked now doesn't work...

Ps. Both: stopImmediatePropagation() and evn.preventDefault() don't help.

- OL3 v 3.20.1
- Chrome v 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit)
- IE v 11.0.38

Comment: Are you using the popup with `ol.Overlay`? If so, do you have the overlay configured with `stopEvent: true`?

Comment: Yes I have 
"stopEvent: true"
This code worked well before 1 - 2 months, maybe it's some change on Chrome and IE... I don't know.